# Is there any more lightweight portable PHP+Apache solution for wordpress development?

Tags: php, mysql, css, wordpress, xhtml

currently i'm using this [XAMPP Lite 1.7.3](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646)

```
  + Apache 2.2.14 (IPV6 enabled)
  + MySQL 5.1.41 (Community Server) with PBXT engine 1.0.09-rc
  + PHP 5.3.1 (PEAR)
  + Miniperl 5.10.1
  + XAMPP Control Version 2.5.8 (ApacheFriends Edition)
  + XAMPP CLI Bundle 1.6
  + XAMPP Port Check 1.5
  + XAMPP Security 1.1
  + SQLite 2.8.17
  + SQLite 3.6.20
  + OpenSSL 0.9.8l
  + phpMyAdmin 3.2.4
  + msmtp 1.4.19 (a sendmail compatible SMTP client)
  + Webalizer 2.21-02 (with GeoIP lite)
  + Ming 0.4.3 for PHP
  + PDF with pdflib lite v7.0.4p4 for PHP
```

Do i need all these things just for making and testing Wordpress Theme? Is there any other good lightweight alternative with only needed things?

What thing needed for Wordpress development only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [Z-WAMP](http://zwamp.sf.net). The components are more updated than the specs you mentioned above. And they have the minimum necessary to run WP. Also portable and only 18MB download.